# Use docker image without jupyter auto starting

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I'm using the Docker image jupyter/scipy-notebook (which includes lot of packages and launches and jupyter notebook with them).

Problem: When  I want to use the notebook and, with the same packages, run files with the terminal., I can't, because I cant kill the notebook without killing the container.

How can I modify the image in order to delete the auto-run of the notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `entrypoint` and `command` for the image are defined here: https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/6c85e4b4/base-notebook/Dockerfile#L108-L109

```
ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "-g", "--"]
CMD ["start-notebook.sh"]
```

You can edit these to run the container without the notebook server. You can either define new ones in your own dockerfile, or you could overwrite them on the command line. eg:

```
docker run --it --rm --entrypoint=bash jupyter/scipy-notebook echo hi
```

`echo hi` is the command in this place. With this image specifically you'll need to overwrite both to prevent the notebook server from starting.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I'm new with Docker

Comment: Completely reasonable mistake, I forget about entrypoints all the time :)